# How does the Earth's radial acceleration affect it's velocity during orbit around Sun?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, earth, sun

When the earth moves along its ellipse at $67,000mph $  it accelerates at $0.006m/s^2$ would it be correct to say it's speed at some points relatively increases by $0.006m/s$ every second

Comment: Your previous question also uses the same incorrect orbital velocity for Earth (it's 67,000 mph = 108,000 kph = 30 km/s).  Please edit your questions.

Comment: I voted to close as you need to do some basic research into forces and how they work in orbits.

Comment: sorry about that. I meant 67,000mph. I 'll edit the question

Comment: You might have a look at [this webpage](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/circles/Lesson-4/Circular-Motion-Principles-for-Satellites) explaining forces in orbits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to trust your numbers here and assume they are true.

So in general, just because an object is undergoing acceleration of magnitude $a$ does not mean that the magnitude of its velocity will increase by $a \, \Delta t$ over some time period (even if we use an infinitesimal time period over which the acceleration can be taken to be constant, i.e. $\text d v=a \, \text d t$). This is because acceleration and velocity are vectors.

For example, for an object undergoing uniform circular motion, the magnitude of the velocity is constant, even though the acceleration is non-zero. Acceleration can change the direction of the velocity vector without affecting it's magnitude.

So no, I don't think the statement you ask about is correct. It would only be true if the acceleration was parallel to the velocity. ${}$

Comment: are you saying in essence for rotating masses acceleration is not parallel to velocity vector. so if the earth's acceleration was e.g. $10,000m/s^2$  given initial conditions for $0.006m/s^2$ it's velocity still remains $670,000mph$

Comment: the numbers I used are relative approximates of the real values

Comment: @LiNKeR Acceleration does not necessarily change the magnitude of velocity. If the acceleration is perpendicular to the velocity the magnitude of the velocity does not change.